# Specialize C++11 template based on type traits while allowing fallback for other types

Tags: c++11, templates, overloading, fallback, type-deduction

I am currently working on serializing several data structures to JSON.

The existing data structures already provide a text-based output format that I want to use as the default when the functions that convert a specific type to JSON not yet exists.

I currently have the fallback and several specific specializations done. As the JSON-library I use is already able to consume primintives like int, float etc. without any extra work, I want these types have their own (common) specialized template function.

My current main problem is that I'm not able to get `to_json(1)` to call the function for fundamentals/primitives, but if I specify the type manually (`to_json<int>`) the correct function is called. Is there any way to fix this? What type does the compiler deduce in the first line?

I am limited to C++11.

The following summarizes my basic setup

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Should rely on fallback
struct S {
};

// Has specialization
struct R {
};


// Fallback. Should catch everything not caught by the specializations
template <typename T>
void to_json(const T& x);


// Specialization for R
template<>
void to_json(const R& x)
{
    std::cout << "For R\n";
}

// Does not work
// Specialization for all fundamentals (e.g. int)
template<typename T>
void to_json(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T>::type& x)
{
    std::cout << "For fundamentals\n";
}

template <typename T>
void to_json(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << "General\n";
}

int main()
{
    to_json(1);      // General. (WRONG, expected fundamentals)
    to_json<int>(1); // fundamentals (CORRECT)
    to_json(R{});    // R (CORRECT)
    to_json(S{});    // General (CORRECT)

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
General
For fundamentals
For R
General
```

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template. Your second templated `to_json` is an overload, not a specialization. Plus, the way you defined its parameter, it's non-deducible context: `T` cannot be deduced from the argument. Put SFINAE on the return type, not on the parameter type; though I suspect you would then have ambiguous overload.

Comment: Something [along these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/378aKcjo6) perhaps, using a helper class that can in fact be partially specialized.

Comment: Are you really need C++11? We have 2023 and using a 12 year outdated standard looks a bit mysterious. Using an up to date compiler with "concepts" available simplifies such tasks a lot. Readable and easy to maintain code helps not only today...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Igor. Nice approach with the helper class, seems like a good solution. That being said, billz' solution (adapted to C++11), seems a bit simpler. As for the choice of standard, Kaus I'm afraid that's outside of my control, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forward declare template function will capture all types. It gives trouble when initialise with concrete type.

```
//// Fallback. Should catch everything not caught by the specializations
//template <typename T>
//void to_json(const T& x);
```

Below code should work fine:

```
// Should rely on fallback
struct S {
};

// Has specialization
struct R {
};

// note: also use enable_if_t to exclude fundamental type
//       otherwise compiler is still confused by the redefinition
template <typename T,
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, bool> = true>
void to_json(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << "General\n";
}
    
// Specialization for R
template<>
void to_json(const R& x)
{
    std::cout << "For R\n";
}

// Specialization for all fundamentals (e.g. int)
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, bool> = true>
void to_json(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << "For fundamentals\n";
}

int main()
{
    to_json(1);      // General. (WRONG, expected fundamentals)
    to_json<int>(1); // fundamentals (CORRECT)
    to_json(R{});    // R (CORRECT)
    to_json(S{});    // General (CORRECT)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It does not compile with C++11 (`enable_if_t` is C++14), however. It works if we write e.g. `std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type* = nullptr`. Please let me know if this rewrite has any (known) adverse side effects.

Comment: Correction: `typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, bool>::type=true` is probably a better solution